# Can a woman daven shacharit after chatzot (midday) has passed?

Tags: halacha, zemanim, shacharis-morning-prayer

Because tefilla is a time bound mitzvah, if a woman has accidentally not davened by the time 6 hours into the day has passed (chatzot), should she still daven shacharit?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109457/discussion-on-question-by-daniel-can-a-female-daven-after-the-zman-has-passed).

Answer (score 4):

Common sense says no... being exempt of time-bound *mitzva* does not mean that they can ignore time altogether, otherwise we would see women take *lulav* at *chanuka*...

Comment: +1 excellent argument. There are many other problems with the assumptions of the question (is prayer really a time-bound command (maybe\), are women exempt from it even if it is (no), etc.) but this is good enough for here.

Answer (score 1):

She should not daven after chaztot. [See halichot shlomo 8:42](http://olamot.net/shiur/%D7%97%D7%99%D7%95%D7%91-%D7%A0%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94)

בספר הליכות שלמה פרק שמיני סע' מב מובא בשם הגרש"ז אויערבך: "נהגו העולם שנשים מתפללות עד חצות, ויש להם על מי שיסמוכו, ומכל מקום עדיף שלא תעשה כן". ובהערה הוסיף: ואף אשה שמתפללת רק תפילה אחת ביום, טוב יותר שלא תתפלל בכה"ג שחרית אלא מנחה.